# How to set a custom user agent in ruby

Tags: ruby, user-agent, net-http

I've a task to test different user agents on a URL through automation. I'm using ruby to code, and I've been trying to set an user agent using the following method, but it doesn't seem to recognize the user agent.

```
@http = Net::HTTP.new(URL)
response = @http.request_get(URL, {'User-Agent' => useragent})
```

Is there any other way to do this, or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 31):

```
http = Net::HTTP.new("your.site.com", 80)
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new("/path/to/the/page.html", {'User-Agent' => 'your_agent'})
response = http.request(req)
puts response.body
```

Works great for me.

Comment: Is there a way to set it globally so you don't have to set the hash on each call?

Answer (score 23):

Also another that work for me :

```
require 'open-uri'
html = open('http://your.site.com/the/page.html', 'User-Agent' => 'Ruby').read
puts html
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

The included [Net::HTTPHeader](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPGenericRequest.html) has the  [initialize_http_header](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPHeader.html#method-i-initialize_http_header) method:

```
@http = Net::HTTP.new(URL)
@http.initialize_http_header({'User-Agent' => useragent})
response = @http.request_get(URL)
```

HTH

Comment: You're calling this on the wrong class. WIll not work.

Comment: @user2398029 this was true to 1.9.3. edits are welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to find a solution that works for both `https` and supplying a header.  Here is a version that works:

```
require "net/http"

uri = URI("https://pokemongolive.com/events/community-day/")

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
request["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36"

response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, :use_ssl => (uri.scheme == 'https')) {|http|
  http.request(request)
}

puts response.code
puts response.body
```

The Ruby version being used was: `ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580)`

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'net/https'

uri = URI('https://example.com')
params = {
  'user-agent' => '...'
}

res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri, params)
puts res.code
puts res.body
```

Comment: Please read "[answer]" and "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.